# php/js tool or function to prevent getting "Unexpected ILLEGAL" when printing from php into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've checked a number of other questions and solutions out concerning this error, but the error persists and I know there's probably a list of characters that I can't include in a javascript string. I wanted to get the list and loop through my php array to escape those chars before doing this:

```
var learnerUpdatedInfo = '<?php echo implode("#", array_keys($record)) . "%%" . implode("{[]}", $record); ?>';
if(opener != null){
opener.document.form1.returnValue.value=learnerUpdatedInfo;
}
```

but I thought there might be a function that php or js/jquery has that does it for you. 
are there any such functions?
thanks!

Comment: What does the end result output look like? Does it include any unescaped single quotes?

Comment: Hi Michael;
   var learnerName = 'coach_id#first_name#last_name#abstract#profile_picture#position#age#gender#training_needed#strengths#CV#MOU_cleared#hours_of_coaching#website#registration_key#registration_confirmed#ID%%2{[]}Richard{[]}Bezuidenhout{[]}Why on earth would a spammer target a search engine on your blog? Because their ranking system relies so heavily on PageRank people can sometimes game the system in whats called `Google Bombing`{[]}/28367884_4d07b1eb32.jpg{[]}gevolver{[]}31{[]}0{[]}0{[]}{[]}{[]}1{[]}38{[]}www.e-magination.com{[]}MzMy{[]}1{[]}35';

Comment: note that the words Google Bombing was wrapped in two of these: \`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually constructing your own format, you should use [JSON](http://json.org/):

```
var learnerString = <?php
    echo json_encode(array("s"=>json_encode($record))); ?>.s;
if(opener != null){
    opener.document.form1.returnValue.value = learnerString;
}
```

Modify the consumer of returnValue to accept JSON as well. For example, in php you'll get started with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: Hi phihag,
already tried your solution before getting to this, that's the reason I'm returning a string.
when I assign a json object to an input, the value is set to a json object, but no members of that object are set;
ie. they all show up as "undefined"

Comment: @pyruva You're right in that the value is an object, and not a string. Updated the answer. If that string continues to be `{}`, please post a link to your code, or better yet, a testcase. Make sure to check that `$record` is not actually empty.

Comment: Hi, checked that $record is not empty. . .it is not, will post the result just now

Comment: I cannot use json_decode in the parent window, since I'm merely setting the value of an input field in the parent window, at this time I can only use javascript since the page was already loaded.